# Decompress logged GZIP binary data

Tags: proxy, logging, gzip, tcpdump

In an effort to verify my app was sending back and forth with my server correctly, I had run

```
tcpdump -w ~/capture.txt -s 0 port 80
```

on a server with proxy sitting in between to capture all requests.  This worked great except that my browser and server are configured to use gzip when sending data.  I now have a capture.txt file with a bunch of binary data.  What is the simplest way that I can decode this data to verify that my api calls are working correctly?

I had tried copying the binary payload of the requests into a separate file and then gunzipping them but this wasn't working... I just want the simplest way to see the plain text version of what is being sent back and forth.

Comment: Disable compression temporarily on the server and client. Assuming you're testing with a non-production server.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that very easily.  Is there any simple program I can put the gzipped data in to just decompress it. I know there must be.

Comment: right that is the first thing I tried and it had said encoding error. I copied the binary payload into a separate file and tried to gunzip it but it didn't work

Comment: gzip might have a "container" in its file format that you're missing in your data (similar to an imaged compressed with JPEG is stored in a JFIF file). I'm not sure, I'm not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's any commands to gunzip just the zipped bits of a file. I think you'll have to figure out a way to get tcpdump to pipe output that is compressed through gunzip before putting it in the file.

On a side note, why don't you use something like curl http://server/api > apilog.txt ? Or is the client a mobile device?

Comment: In this case the client is a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

> I now have a capture.txt file with a bunch of binary data.

Or, more correctly, you have a [pcap file](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html), with the misleading suffix `.txt` ("misleading" because it's not a text file - the output of tcpdump's `-w` is *never* a text file!), which, by definition, is a bunch of binary data.

> This worked great except that my browser and server are configured to use gzip when sending data.

Try loading the pcap file in [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org); it has code to un-gzip gzipped payloads.